# I want to regulate 52 volt to 44 volt with applying different pwm signal

Tags: power, mosfet, power-electronics, opto-isolator, pmos

I just want to regulate 52 volt to 44 volt with different pwm signal from arduino through a optocoupler 4n35.I just use this circuit in which i used 6 pmos and 6 optocoupler...i applied 52 volt and 45 amp to get voltage between 52 to 44 but when i try to regulate the circuit it failed all the MOSFET have burnt.The output of this circuit is going to connect to motor driver circuit please help to find...is there any alternative circuit to control if then please post here
[image]

Comment: Please draw the full schematic, since the way you have drawn it now implies the optocouplers are not correctly implemented. Please also draw all the voltages and the load impedance.

Comment: Optocoupler 6 th pin is connected to gnd and load is bldc motor of 1000w 48 volt...

Comment: I would draw that information in the schematic to clear up the question for new readers. Also crop the black borders.

Comment: Okay I will redrw and again post it later

Comment: PIn numbers on DIP components like your optocoupler go counter-clockwise around the package - pin 6 should be the top right pin, not bottom right.

Comment: i have just changed please take a look

Comment: Have you put heatsinks on the FETs or are they bare TO-220?

Comment: I would add an Inductor and implement this as a buck converter. Or better - use off the shelf controller to do the pwm and just apply reference signal for it.

Comment: Yes i put heatsink